# Regex for matching full word starting with # (Javascript)

Tags: regex

I want to match a separate word which starts with # character.

```
enter #code here - #code
some#string here - nothing
#test - #test
```

I came up with following regex:

```
   "enter #code here".replace(/\b#[\w]*/gi, "REPLACED")
```

But it doesn't work. After some testing i found that

```
   "enter #code here".replace(/#\b[\w]*/gi, "REPLACED")
```

works just fine.

Now can someone explain why \b# part is incorrect in this case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\b` is a transition between a non-word character and a word character, or vice-versa. Because a `'#'` is not a word character, your first expression will only match a string that has a word character directly before the `#`.

What might work is the expression `/(\W)#[\w]*/gi`, because your second example will match any of those three strings. Use a backreference to put the non-word character from the match expression into the replacement.

Comment: If your engine supports it (Javascript doesn't), you could use a [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) instead of the capturing group to not capture the `\W`: `/(?<=\W)#[\w]*/gi`

Answer (score 1):

The change between the `#` and `[\w]` is a non-word transition to word boundary, so `\b` matches that, but a space to `#` is not a boundary transition.

Your "works just fine" regex incorrectly replaces the "#string" in `some#string here` where you say it shouldn't: `"some#string here".replace(/#\b[\w]*/gi, "REPLACED");` gave me `"someREPLACED here"`

What I think you want is whitespace vs. non-white with the 'sharp' (and you don't need the brackets around the `\w`) so the regex I came up with is

```
>>> "enter #code here".replace(/(\W)#\w*/gi, "$1REPLACED");
"enter REPLACED here"
>>> "some#string here".replace(/(\W)#\w*/gi, "$1REPLACED");
"some#string here"
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, i incorrectly understood \b character.